# Sentence Structure Question

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

What kind of clause or phrase is used in the first part of the following sentence (*Frail and seemingly disoriented at times*)? Would you elaborate on its structure.

> Frail and seemingly disoriented at times, he is looking vulnerable.

Comment: Related question, [Is this use of present participle grammatically correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15882/is-this-use-of-present-participle-grammatically-correct). You can Google participle (-pial) construction, participle clause (phrase) or absolute construction (clause), adverbial clause, etc. to find how it works.

Comment: It's an adjective phrase called a 'predicative adjunct'. Predicative because it relates to a predicand ("he") and adjunct because it's a supplementary piece of information, non essential, detached from the rest of the clause by a comma (and by a short pause in speech). It's comparable with the predicative complement in "he was frail and seemingly disorientated at times"; we understand that the property of being frail and seemingly disorientated at times applies to the referent of "he".

Comment: @BillJ: Is "Frail and seemingly disoriented at times" adverbial phrase or adjective phrase?

Comment: @Mani Category-wise, it's an adjective phrase, comprising a coordination of two adjective phrases "frail" and "seemingly-disorientated at times" (or a coordinated adjective phrase if you prefer). Its function in the clause is that of adjunct (sometimes called an 'adverbial').

Comment: It's also called by some an 'absolute' construction. These may (Her hair flowing in the wind, she raced across the beach.) or may not (Playing on his i-Pad / Happy with his lolly, the boy sat on the sand.) an initial noun phrase.

Answer (score 1):

In comments BillJ wrote:

> It's an adjective phrase called a 'predicative adjunct'. Predicative because it relates to a predicand ("he") and adjunct because it's a supplementary piece of information, non essential, detached from the rest of the clause by a comma (and by a short pause in speech). It's comparable with the predicative complement in "he was frail and seemingly disorientated at times"; we understand that the property of being frail and seemingly disorientated at times applies to the referent of "he".
>
> Category-wise, it's an adjective phrase, comprising a coordination of two adjective phrases "frail" and "seemingly-disorientated at times" (or a coordinated adjective phrase if you prefer). Its function in the clause is that of adjunct (sometimes called an 'adverbial').

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/601225/2085).